# Is there any way I could improve the speed of this Python Program?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter

I re-created the game Lights Out using Python and Tkinter and as far as I know there are no bugs but it is very slow especially if you set the grid size to be much higher then 10x10 (I have a slider in game that lets you do this.) I was just wondering if you had any ideas on how I could get it to run faster.

```
#Nicholas Eckstein
#Lights Out
#11/20/14
import random
import math
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Lastx, lasty = 0,0
GridSize="410x520"

def reset():#Resets the grid size to the size set in the slider and randomizes cells.
    global grid                                   
    global GridSize
    gridMaker()
    canvas.delete("all")#Clears the screen
    ResetMin=math.trunc(len(grid)/3)              ##Picks random amount of cells to switch states.
    ResetMax=math.trunc(len(grid)/2)               #Amount chosen is relative to the grid size.
    ResetAmount=random.randint(ResetMin,ResetMax) ##(Random amount in between 1/2 and 1/3 of the cells.
    iterate=0                                     
    while iterate<ResetAmount:#Picks random cells to switch states until iterate==ResetAmount
        #cell=random.choice(grid)#All cells exist in a list of lists called grid.
        #cell.pop(2)             #A single list inside the Grid List is a cell.
        #cell.append(1)          #This Cell consists of 2 ranges and a state. [range(105, 125), range(5, 25), 0]
        #iterate+=1              #The first range is the width of the cell, the second range is for the height, and the last number is for the state.
                                #The grid list looks something like this: [[range(105, 125), range(5, 25), 0], [range(125, 145), range(5, 25), 0], [range(145, 165), range(5, 25), 0]...]
        cell=random.choice(grid)
        cellx=cell[0][5]
        celly=cell[1][5]
        iterate+=1
        CellSwitcher(cellx,celly)
    GridSize=str((len(grid)/2)*20)+"x"+str(((len(grid)/2)*20)+110)#This sets the gridsize to the size determined by the slider
    art()



def art():#Takes the information from the Grid list and "draws" the cells.
    for cell in grid:
        if cell[2]==1:
            canvas.create_rectangle(cell[0][0],cell[1][0],cell[0][19],cell[1][19],fill="white")
            canvas.create_rectangle(cell[0][0]+2,cell[1][0]+2,cell[0][19],cell[1][19],fill="black",outline="black")
        else:
            canvas.create_rectangle(cell[0][0],cell[1][0],cell[0][19],cell[1][19],fill="black")
            canvas.create_rectangle(cell[0][0]+2,cell[1][0]+2,cell[0][19],cell[1][19],fill="white",outline="white")


def xy(event):#Takes the position of the mouse click
    global lastx, lasty
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y
    CellSwitcher(lastx,lasty)

def CellSwitcher(lastx,lasty):#Switches the states of the cells neighboring the cell you clicked.
    for coord in grid:
        if lastx in coord[0] and lasty in coord[1]:
            if coord[2]==0:
                coord.pop(2)  
                coord.append(1)
            else:     
                coord.pop(2) 
                coord.append(0)

            if [coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21),0] in grid:                    ####
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21),0])].pop(2)       #
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21)])].append(1)     #
            elif [coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21),1] in grid:                      # Switch Top Neighbor's state
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21),1])].pop(2)      #
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]+20,coord[1][19]+21)])].append(0)      #
                                                                                              ####

            if [coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19),0] in grid:                    ####
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19),0])].pop(2)       #
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19)])].append(1)     # 
            elif [coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19),1] in grid:                      # Switch Bottom Neighbor's state
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19),1])].pop(2)      #
                grid[grid.index([coord[0],range(coord[1][0]-20,coord[1][19]-19)])].append(0)      #
                                                                                              ####

            if [range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1],0] in grid:                    ####
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1],0])].pop(2)       #
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1]])].append(1)     #
            elif [range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1],1] in grid:                      # Switch Right Neighbor's state
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1],1])].pop(2)      #
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]+20,coord[0][19]+21),coord[1]])].append(0)      #
                                                                                              ####

            if [range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1],0] in grid:                    ####
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1],0])].pop(2)       #
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1]])].append(1)     #
            elif [range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1],1] in grid:                      # Switch Left Neighbor's state
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1],1])].pop(2)      #
                grid[grid.index([range(coord[0][0]-20,coord[0][19]-19),coord[1]])].append(0)      #
                                                                                              ####
    art()



root = Tk()#Create the window
root.geometry(GridSize)#Set Window Size
root.resizable(0,0)#Stop people from resizing the window
root.title("Lights Out")

canvas = Canvas(root,background=root.cget('bg'))#Create the part of the window that draws the grid
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xy)#Detect clicking and send coordinates of mouse
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)#Resize canvas to window size and allign.


SizeLabel = Label(root,text="Grid Size")#Write the "reset" label
SizeLabel.pack()#Allign Label

Size = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=400,width=20,sliderlength=60,from_=1,to=20,tickinterval=1)#Create, orientate, and set the size of the slider
Size.set(10)#Set starting position for slider
Size.pack()#Allign Slider

Reset = Button(root,text ="Reset",command = reset)#Create the reset button
Reset.pack()#Allign the reset button

def gridMaker():#This function creates the grid list.
    global grid 
    grid=[]
    xCoord=205-(int(math.trunc(Size.get())/2)*20)#Centers the grid
    yCoord=5
    iterate=0
    while yCoord<Size.get()*20:
        grid.append([range(xCoord,xCoord+20),range(yCoord, yCoord+20),0])#Adds a cell to the grid list with the ranges based on what xCoord and yCoord are.         
        if Size.get()%2==1:#Tests to see if the grid size is odd or even
            if xCoord<205+(int(math.trunc(Size.get())/2)*20):
                xCoord+=20
            else:
                xCoord=205-(int(math.trunc(Size.get())/2)*20)
                yCoord+=20
        else:
            if xCoord<205+(int(math.trunc(Size.get())/2)*20)-20:
                xCoord+=20
            else:
                xCoord=205-(int(math.trunc(Size.get())/2)*20)
                yCoord+=20



gridMaker()#Draws the grid
reset()#Adds Randomizes Cell States

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is your profiler output?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it to see which parts take the most time?

Comment: Something went wrong with your edit. Most of the code is gone, and half the title is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CellSwitcher` function iterates over all items in the cell, when it eventually only modifies nine cells (itself and its 8 neighbors), right? Why iterate over every single cell? If you know the cell that was clicked (eg: row 3, column 2) you can easily compute the neighboring cells. So, part of the answer is to remove the iteration over all of the cells and replace it with a direct lookup of the clicked-on cell and its neighbors.

Also, your reset function calls `CellSwitcher` which seems like overkill. If you're randomly setting the color of each cell, why go through CellSwitcher, since it changes the colors of all its neighbors?

Perhaps the biggest culprit is that you are recreating all of the canvas objects on each call to `CellSwitcher`, without deleting any of the old objects. There's no reason to do that -- create all of the canvas objects just once and then change them with the [itemconfig](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) method of the canvas.

The canvas has performance problems when you have lots of items. In your case, after the GUI first comes up you've already created 9800 canvas items. Click on a single cell and the canvas now has 10,200 items. And so on. The canvas can pretty easily handle thousands of items, even tens of thousands. However, when I move the slider to 20 you end up creating a whopping 125,600 objects on the canvas which will definitely cause the canvas to under-perform.